# Git merge conflict markers are missing whilst retrying an aborted rebase?

Tags: git

I was half way through re-basing my branch `git pull --rebase origin master`. During the rebase I fixed a couple of merge conflicts, added them `git add FILE`, `git rebase --continue`.

However I decided to start again as I was not happy with my progress. I used `git rebase --abort` to end the rebase.

When I now do `git pull --rebase origin master` I notice that all the merge conflict markers have disappeared and I think the resolutions to the conflicts in my first attempt have remained.

Am I correct in thinking when I start the rebase again I should see the same merge conflicts I saw when i first started the rebase? If so how do I get back to this state?

P.S

I am using Pycharm, could Pycharm be being too helpful?

UPDATE: I checked this with atom and VIM and its the same issue so it's not an IDE/editor thing.

Comment: Well I _would_ expect to see the same conflicts, but are you at the same step in the rebase where the conflicts actually happened?

Comment: This could be due to [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere), do you happen to have `rerere.enabled` in your git config? You can try to manually have it forget the settings with one of the commands such as `git rerere clear` or `git rerere forget <path>`, see the manual page for more details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @filbranden I was able to resolve this:

1. `git pull --rebase origin master`
2. `git rerere forget filepath`

   ```
   Updated preimage for 'filepath'`
   Forgot resolution for 'filepath`
   ```
3. `git rebase --abort`

This cleared all the saved conflict resolutions I had already done.
 When I tried `git pull --rebase origin master` again I was back at the start of rebase which is what I wanted.